# Entrecomillado en PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día, tengo esta consulta que se envía desde php a mysql, sin embargo al enviar comillas dentro de las variables éstas, obviamente generan un fallo cuando se ejecutan en mysql.

Este es la consulta enviada.

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO fallas (fecha, n_caso, clase_falla, descripcion, tipo_evento, estado, tipo_falla, 
            fk_proceso, fk_entrega, fecha_creacion, cantidad_reprocesos, incidente_mayor, fk_proyecto) 
            VALUES ('$fecha','$n_caso','$clase_falla','$descripcion', '$tipo_evento', '$estado_falla','$tipo_falla',
            '$fk_proceso','$fk_entrega','$fecha2', 1, 'No','$fk_proyecto')";
```

Mi pregunta va a dirigida hacia qué puedo hacer para que mysql pueda interpretar el intercomillado como parte de la información a insertar (Ocurre únicamente en la variable $descripcion la cual es tipo varchar en la BD).

Comment: Hola Andres, debes escapar la comilla usando un str_replace("'","\'",$descripcion); o la función mysql_real_escape_string, en todo caso yo te recomendaría usar la mysql_real_escape_string para todas las variables y asi evitas injecciones de SQL.

Comment: Disculpa, ¿Sería mucha molestia darme algún ejemplo o link donde pueda aprender a usar la función mysql_real_escape_string?, si que conozco str_replace, pero ya que recomiendas la otra función me gustaría saber como funciona.

Comment: En la web de PHP puedes encontrar como manejar la funcion mysql_real_scape_string y mysqli_real_scape_string según sea tu caso, de igual forma te recomiendo usar mysqli para todas tus conexiones a MySQl. https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Agregando una información adicional, te recomiendo no enviar variables directamente a tu consulta, ya que permite la [inyección de SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

En la web de PHP puedes encontrar como manejar la función:

- mysql_real_scape_string y
- mysqli_real_scape_string

Según sea tu caso, de igual forma te recomiendo usar mysqli para todas tus conexiones a MySQl.

- https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Mira [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Hola, eres un usuario que lleva algo de tiempo en el sitio, por favor revisa [answer] y modifica tu pregunta por favor, saludos.